# Is it possible to use anonymous objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Seems like it works

```
console.log({name: 'fred', age: 65}.name);  //fred
console.log({name: 'fred', age: 65}.age);   //65
```

until I try to use a method

```
{greet(){console.log('hello');}}.greet();   //Uncaught SyntaxError: unexcted token: '{'
```

Assigning an identical object literal to a const and then invoking its method works

```
const greeter = {greet(){console.log('hello');}};
greeter.greet();                                    //hello
```

Is such usage not allowed?

Comment: You can assign an anonymous object to a named var and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just lack `()` to properly call the anonymous object

```js
({ greet() { console.log('hello'); } }).greet() // hello
```